# How can I print the string value of something wrapped in another type in Ocaml?

Tags: printing, types, ocaml, printf

I'm attempting to use Printf.sprintf to print out a value that is within a type of multiple options

```
type tid = int

type lock = string

type rdwrlock = 
  | Rdlock of lock
  | Wrlock of lock

type rdwrlockid = rdwrlock * tid
```

Basically, I want to print out a `rdwrlockid`, which is `(rdwrlock*tid)` and I can print out the `tid` easily using the `%d` option in `printf`, but how do I access the string within the `lock` within the `rdwrlock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking to your example it could be done as follows:

```
let y, z = (Rdlock "a", 1) in
Printf.printf "%d %s\n" z (match y with Rdlock r -> r | Wrlock w -> w)
```

It may be simplified a bit:

```
type lck = READ | WRITE
type lckid = lck * tid

let k, i = (READ, 1) in
Printf.printf "%d %s\n" i (match k with READ -> "R" | WRITE -> "W");
```

Or if you do need string representation of `lock` oftenly, you may write a helper function:

```
let string_of_lock k =
    match k with
    | READ  -> "R"
    | WRITE -> "W"
```

And then use it in printf:

```
Printf.printf "%d %s\n" i (string_of_lock k)
```